# How I do specific merging between 2 text files(or 1 text file and 1 string) in C language?

Tags: c, file

I have 2 text files or 1 text file and 1 string with next form:

**file1.txt**

Line1 ....

Line2....

{

line3..

line4 ..

}

line5..

**file2.txt or a string**

line1 ...

line2 ...

{

}

line5...

line11 ...

**Result: another .txt file or the same file1.txt**

Line1 ....

Line2....

{

line3..

line4..

}

line 5...

line11 ...

I would like to do a specific merge in C and what is between this characters { } I don't want to be overwritten, only what is before and after these (if they are different line, of course). Any hint will be great!

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: You should better specify your *specific merge*: do you want lines from first file, or second file is they are different, what if a line from first file is in second but at a different line number... And to begin with: *what have you tried so far?*

Comment: In first file I have text between this character { } and I don't want to overwrite  wit text from the second file. In second file I have the same text like in the first file but with other text between { } or more text before and after to { }. This text from the second file I want to insert in first file,but I want to insert inside the text not at the end of file. I tried some method but I insert at the end of file and I don't want this.